# PyCharm font size got too big

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, pycharm, jetbrains-ide, configuration-files

I was setting the font size of PyCharm's appearance window since it was too small, accidentally from 21 it became 213, now I am unable to do anything about it.

How can I change or revert it back to original? I have tried uninstalling it from snap and reinstalling but nothing changed. I am using Ubuntu Stable Release.

Comment: Are you able to use PyCharm's GUI at all (to go into the Settings)? If not, then the only option is to delete the actual config files. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#d0c62d5e

Answer (score 0):

Follow this guide from their official website: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-project-and-ide-settings.html

**1.** From the main menu, select

> File > Manage IDE Settings > Restore Default Settings

**If you can't use the mouse,**

> Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> twice and type `Restore default settings`.

**2.** Click Restore and Restart. The IDE will be restarted with the default configuration.